# Dropdown Validation in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am working on dropdown validation using jQuery. I want the user to select at least one value from the dropdown, but this is not working for me.

```html
<select name="skills[]" multiple="multiple" class="3cols actives">
  <option value="Baker">Bakers</option>
  <option value="Barista">Barista</option>
  <option value="Bartender">Bartender</option>
</select>
```

```js
(function($, W, D) {
  var JQUERY4U = {};
  JQUERY4U.UTIL = {
    setupFormValidation: function() {
      //form validation rules
      $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
          name: "required",
          url: {
            required: true,
            url: true
          },
          skills[]: {
            required: true,
          },
```

Comment: When is `JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation()` called? Does `#myForm` exist? The `skills[]` key needs to be placed in quotes. This only seems to be half of your code.

Comment: `skills[]: {` isn't valid, maybe this should be: `"skills[]": {` or maybe you can give your `select` a different name?